# How to prevent iOS from showing NFC scanned website popup when app is open

Tags: ios, flutter, nfc

I'm creating Flutter app that uses NFC interaction. Specifically, I'm using the nfc_manager package.

I have solved this issue on Android (as it was an issue in the repository), but I'm having the same problem on iOS and can't find a solution.

I'm wondering if it's just something I need to declare in the info.plist file, but I'm not sure.

Thanks for any help.

Here's what I did for Android so you have some context:

[Stop Pop up when app is open (Android Solution)](https://github.com/okadan/flutter-nfc-manager/issues/71)

The goal is that when I have my app open, and the phone comes in contact with another NFC device, that the phone ignores it. I only want the NFC interactions to be specific to what I'm doing with the app. Nothing else should affect it as far as NFC goes.

Comment: If you don't have an active NFC session in your app then iOS will always prompt the user if it reads a tag with a url https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/adding_support_for_background_tag_reading

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 I guess that's just the way it's going to be on iOS then.